# Grails, executing a javascript by clicking on a column in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

I have a view consisting of two lists: products and offers. You can select several rows by checking checkboxes on them and then by clicking on a link, offer lines will be created for each selected product.
Every offer line has the id of the product which I will use to list all offers created for that product in a list below the list of products.

I tried to solve that by using a javascript which should be activated when you click on a link or field in the product list.
The script sends a message to the controller that creates the list of offers for this product and then render a template in this view.

I can just use a link and call the controller and the template will be rendered but of course not the rest of the view.

So I need to have line:

```
<td><g:link action="listOffers" id="${pb.id}">${pb.volumeOffered}</g:link></td>
```

replaced with something better that can call my javascript-function.
I read somewhere you could put an -onclick="javascript-function" in the g:link tag but it doesn't work.

Below is the most important part of controller and gsp in this case.

In the List.gsp:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function listOffers(id){
        $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'listOffers' )}',
        data: [id],
        type: 'get'
        }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
        }
    </script>    
.....
.....
    <g:render template="ListOffers" model="[offerDetails:offerDetails]"/>
```

In the template _AvailableProductData.gsp:

```
    <g:each in="${prodBuffer}" status="i" var="pb"> 
  <tr class="${ (i % 2) == 0 ? 'even': 'odd'}">
                <td><a onclick="listOffers(${pb.id})">${pb.volumeOffered}</a></td>
```

In the template _ListOffers.gsp:

```
<div id="offerList">
    <g:set var="entityName" value='Offers' />
    <div id="list-offers" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <g:sortableColumn property="product" title='Product' />
                    <g:sortableColumn property="volumeOffered" title='Volume' />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <g:each in="${offerDetails}" status="i" var="od">
                    <tr class="${ (i % 2) == 0 ? 'even': 'odd'}">
                        <td><g:link class="edit" action="edit" resource="offerDetail" id="${od?.id}"> ${od.product?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></td>
                        <td>${od?.volumeOffered}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${offersCount ?: 0}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
def listOffers(){
    def List<OfferDetail> offerDetails = getOfferList()
    render(template:"ListOffers", model:[offerDetails: offerDetails])
}
```

Added a printout to see what params contains:

```
def listOffers(){
    System.out.println("#--#"+params)
    def List<OfferDetail> offerDetails = getOfferList()
    render(template:"ListOffers", model:[offerDetails: offerDetails])
}
```

The printout is:

```
#--#[undefined:, controller:ordersAndStore, format:null, action:listOffers]
```

Following is the complete javascript section, the first one is working good but then comes the onclick version that responds and calls the controller but can not send the id. Then comes your version and another one simple but no one is working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function availableProducts(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'availableProducts' )}',
                    data: [sawMill],
                    type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#divToUpdate' ).html( data ); });
        }

        function listOffers(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'listOffers' )}',
                data: [],
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
        }

        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( '.offers' ).click( function ( event ){
                alert('HEJ')
                $.ajax({
                    url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'listOffers' )}',
                    data: [this.id],
                    type: 'get'
                }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
            });
        });
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.test1').bind('click', function (){
            alert('KLICKED');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

And the gsp-part in the template:

```
        <g:each in="${prodBuffer}" status="i" var="pb"> 
            <tr id="{$pb.id}" class="offers" class=" ${ (i % 2) == 0 ? 'even': 'odd'}">
                <td><g:checkBox name="toOffer" value="${pb.id}" checked="false"  /></td>
                <td><g:link action="edit_prodbuffer" id="${pb.id}">${pb.id}</g:link></td>
                <td>${pb.sawMill}</td>
                <td>${pb.product}</td>
                <td>${pb.length}</td>
                <td>${pb.volumeAvailable}</td>
                <td><a  onclick='listOffers()' > ${pb.volumeOffered}</a></td>
```

==================================================

I have taken an old test project which I cleaned and modified to this simple example that still don't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'author.label', default: 'Author')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready( function() {
                $( '.off1' ).click( function ( event ){
                    alert('HEJ');
                });
            });
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#list-author" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="list-author" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <table>
                <th></th>
                <tbody
                    <g:each in="${authorList}" status='i' var='a'>
                        <tr id="${a.id}" class="off1">
                            <td><g:field  type="text" name="author" value="${a?.name}"/> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </g:each>
            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${authorCount ?: 0}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I begin to be desperate, can't make this work but I must :(
I'll list the code again with some different settings and the output.
Sure something must be wrong with my code as others can make it work but what is wrong?

Part of the GSP-file where things start, there is two alternative lines one is commented here.

```
                <g:each in="${authorList}" status='i' var='a'>
                    <tr id="${a.id}" onclick="listOffers(6)">
<!--   This line uses script B ------ <tr id="${a.id}" class="off1">-->
                        <td><g:field  type="text" name="author" value="${a?.name}"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
```

-- Controller:

```
def listOffers() {
    System.out.println("### --- HEJ --- ### "+params)
}
```

-- Script A:

```
    function listOffers(id){
            alert('HEJ<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'+ id);
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'author', action:'listOffers', id:"${id}" )}',
                data: [id],
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
        }
```

-- Script B:

```
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $(".off1").click( function(event){
                alert('HEJ');
            });
        });
```

Script B: never respond - WHY?

Output from controller using script A:

```
### --- HEJ --- ### [undefined:, controller:author, format:null, action:listOffers, id:null]
```

Modified script A -- data is empty:

```
        function listOffers(id){
            alert('HEJ<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'+ id);
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'author', action:'listOffers', id:"${id}" )}',
                data: [],
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
        }
```

Output from controller using modified version of script A:

```
### --- HEJ --- ### [controller:author, format:null, action:listOffers, id:null]
```

The alert call works ok and I get the correct value of id there.
As yo can see from the controller printout id is null and if data contains id I also get 'undefined:' as a parameter.
If I remove id from data, now data[], this 'undefined:' disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in 2 points.
First: In main.gsp I moved the string:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

from the end of the file up to the head close to the css-loading.
This made the script to respond.

But then I couldn't get the data from "id" go in to params.
but by rewriting the row:

```
data:[this.id] to data:{id: this.id}
```

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your  element like this

```
<td><a onclick="listOffers(${pb.id})>${pb.volumeOffered}</a></td>
```

and Jquery function which accept id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function listOffers(id){
    $.ajax({
            url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'listOffers' )}',
    data: [id],
    type: 'get'
    }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data ); });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That was a lift, now the javascript is called and the controller also. But the id is not sent within the params. I added a log print, see at the end of my answer, to see what the params contained. And that was:  #--#[undefined:, controller:ordersAndStore, format:null, action:listOffers] As you can see there is one parameter named undefined and it's empty. There is a few typos in your answer, a missing quote in the gsp-line and the id should be pb.id in the gsp-line.

Comment: I've already done that and the controller receives parameter "undefined:" It looks like it didn't recognize the id-parameter or..?

Comment: Did you tried listOffers('${pb.id}') and listOffers(${pb.id}) both way?  listOffers(${pb.id}) one is working for me. :(

Comment: Strange, it doesn't matter if I put quotes around or not it is just the same. I even tried putting a constant value in there - but nothing else happened.

Answer (score 1):

You could give each table row the ID then respond to events when the row is clicked:

Breaking this down to a simple example with JUST the parts to show how it works.

OrdersAndStoreController

```
class OrdersAndStoreController {

    def index() {
        [prodBuffer: [new ProdBuffer(id: 1, volumeOffered: 100), new ProdBuffer(id: 2, volumeOffered: 200)]]
    }

    def listOffers() {
        render(template:"ListOffers", model:[offerDetails: [offer1: 'offer1', offer2: 'offer2']])
    }
}

class ProdBuffer{
    Integer id
    Integer volumeOffered
}
```

index.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '.offers' ).click( function ( event ){
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'listOffers' )}',
                data: [this.id],
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#offerList' ).html( data );     });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Volume offered</th>
    </thead>
    <g:each in="${prodBuffer}" status="i" var="pb">
        <tr id="${pb.id}" class="offers">
            <td>${pb.volumeOffered}</td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
</table>

<div id="offerList"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

_ListOffers.gsp

```
${offerDetails}
```

Comment: Hmm, looked good but but the tr-tag already use class: <tr class="${ (i % 2) == 0 ? 'even': 'odd'}">. I tried to set the class in the td-tag but the javascript is never fired.

Comment: You can use multiple classes, I removed it for demo so it was clear. The offers class doesn't actually apply any styling, we're just using it as a hook for the javascript

Comment: Well, it still don't fire the javascript, does it matter that table is on a template and not in the same gsp-file as the javascript?

Comment: Try adding the javascript block to the template. If that doesn't work you could add it to a specific javascript file in /assets/javascripts, be sure to add a row to application.js e.g. `//= require myjavascriptfile`

Comment: I have now tested by moving the script to the template, not working, and then created a separate file in asset/javascript but not working. When I think of the onclick-version that fired the javascript, it should work to have the script in the main view. The problem with that version was that I didn't get the id to the controller. No matter how you turn yourself around, you always have your back behind ;-)

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong at your end as this works fine for me, what isn't working exactly? If you put println statements in your listOffers action do they print? What about e.g. an alert( 'here' ); in the javascript block.

Comment: I tested by adding an alert into the script, I also made a simpler script which just calling the alert. But nothing happens, I also have a println in the controller to check but the only version that hits the controller is the onclick-version. I added all scripts at the end of my question above.

Comment: Now I think I tested everything but without success, I added a new small test project with just a main form that contains everything necessary. A click on a row should trigger the script wich calls alert - and that's everything but nothing happens. What have done wrong with this or can it be something wrong with my grails installation? Onclick- works as far as you get the script to execute but I can not get any data forward the controller so I can't use that either.

Comment: Created a new project added your code but it appears the same. The script is totally dead, no response at all. It seems to be something wrong with my grails-installation ? But the other script that is using the onclick that one activates the script and controller couldn't that be used? It also suits me better because I want to have other actions executed when clicking other fields on the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139582/discussion-between-mike-w-and-larand).